# What does work function of metal exactly mean in photoelectric emission?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, metals

When a metal surface is illuminated with light of appropriate frequency so as to cause photoelectric emission, when does the work function of the metal come into play? Is it the energy required to bring an electron to the metal surface or is it the energy required to liberate the electron from the metal surface?

Also, is it possible for any other substance( except metal) to emit photoelectrons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photoelectric effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224769/photoelectric-effect)

Comment: This question has thousand of link try to search on stack exchange before posting!

Comment: @Yuvraj I did search and yes the second part has been answered but that was just a follow up question. I couldn't find any satisfying answers to the first part

Comment: For your other question, I believe the discussion on [What's the difference between the work function and ionisation energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205310/whats-the-difference-between-the-work-function-and-ionisation-energy) should answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work function of a metallic surface is the minimum amount of energy required to liberate an electron.  The rough, classical idea is that electrons are free to move around *inside* a metal, but require extra energy in order to leave.

To answer your second question, yes, non-conductors can emit photoelectrons.  This is the basis of [x-ray photoelectron spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy).

Comment: So if a metal surface whose work function is W is illuminated with photons of energy E and it is given that the electron loses 1/5 th of it's energy due to collisions inside the metal, the final kinetic energy of the electron will be (E/5-W) and not (E-W)/5?